# PUT request with FOSRest BodyConverter

Tags: rest, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm having troubles using BodyConverter, usually I use FOSRest with Symfony Forms but on a new project I'm trying to use BodyConverter. POST requests works fine but I can't get PUT requests to work.

```
/**
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"Default"})
     * @Rest\Put("/{id}", name="put")
     * @ParamConverter("mission", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     *
     * @param Mission $mission
     * @param ConstraintViolationList $violations
     * @return Mission | View
     */
    public function put(Mission $mission, ConstraintViolationList $violations)
    {
        if(count($violations)){
            return $this->view($violations, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return $this->manager->post($mission);
    }
```

With BodyConverter and ParamConverter I would like to update the ressource which ID was passed in the URL but BodyConverter just override the ressource and create a new one. For exemple :

PUT /missions/1 should update mission 1 but it creates a new mission with a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->manager->post($mission);
```

The post seems odd when you want to update (put) an object.

Comment: It's just a method that is common for POST / PUT / PATCH which is used to persist and flush created / updated Mission $mission